# Dataflow diagram creator for Java source code

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

I am searching for data flow diagram creator for Java source code. Please suggest me any tool for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SD Java parser with flow analysis](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html).

You have to export the data flow graph to DOT to see it.  The front end has support to do that.

Comment: Is there any open source tool?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know any software which create data flow diagram from java source code, however, I know that Microsoft Visio has the features of reverse engineering to create data flow diagram. But I don’t know whether it does for java source code or not. I will suggest you to try [Visio 2010](http://www.visiotoolbox.com/2010) for creating DFD. Hope this may help you.